# I installed Bitnami and then XAMPP server, can't access wordpress

Tags: wordpress, server, xampp, localhost

I wanted to start practicing making a wordpress site locally. I installed Bitnami a few days ago, then I concluded I needed XAMPP too in order to check the site mobile responsiveness.

I have configured XAMPP but I can not access wordpress using http://[myipv4]/wordpress

Now I can not access wordpress neither with XAMPP server turned on or off.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: We need you to post the changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made changes just to check the responsive mode, a better and easier choice is to use browser extensions like [this](https://mybrowseraddon.com/mobile-view-switcher.html).

It simply simulates the mobile mode for you and you can change the page size using [Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).